# Unzip archive zip file into folder with same name as archive zip file

Tags: powershell, unzip, 7zip

I am able to successfully unzip a zipped file using a Powershell script as follows:

```
$filePath = "s:\Download Data Feed\"
$zip = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filePath | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".zip" } 

foreach ($file in $zip) { 
Expand-7Zip -ArchiveFileName $file -Password "Password" -TargetPath $filePath
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

The zip file are csv files. But what I would like is to unzip the csv file in a folder of the same name as the zip file itself (just as when you right click the zipped file you can choose to extract it as the file itself or to a folder of the same name as the zip file). I've tried looking at the switches for Expand-7Zip command but can't find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following (I cannot test with `Expand-7Zip`):

```
$filePath = "s:\Download Data Feed\"
$zip = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $filePath | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".zip" }

foreach ($file in $zip) { 
    $target = Join-Path $filePath $file.BaseName
    if (!(Test-Path $target -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $target
    }
    Expand-7Zip -ArchiveFileName $file -Password "Password" -TargetPath $target
}
```

**Explanation:**

Each `FileInfo` object contained in the `$zip` collection has a property, `BaseName`, which is the name of the file without the extension.

[Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7) is used to join a path with a child path. The child path here will be the `BaseName` value of `$file` during each iteration.

[Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7) is used to verify if a path already exists. If the `$target` path does not exist, it will be created due to the [New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7) command.

---

Another approach to getting the target folder path is to simply use a regex replace, which is likely more efficient:

```
$target = $file.FullName -replace '\.zip$'
```